# Is it possible to do a % of Table with an attribute in Tableau?

Tags: attributes, tableau-api, percentage

I have an attribute that contains numbers. I would like to use the % of table function but it doesn't work.  I've set this pill as an attribute because when it's not the sum is incorrect. (much too high)

Help?

Comment: is it possible to see any dataset example and/or any screenshot in order to better understand your needs?

Comment: The problem with attributes is that when they have more than one value when associated with something they become * and not a value.